# Android Login Screen implemented in Model-View-Presenter Pattern

Tags: java, android, mvp

So this is my first time implementing the MVP pattern in Android.

As I understand the presenter should not contain any Android specific code. I am using `TextInputLayout` and I want to validate my text fields and show an error message using `TextinputLayout.setError("")`. Now the edittext validation logic is implemented in the `LoginActivity` but is there any way to separate the logic to the presenter? The code is given below:

This is the `LoginActivity` where I validate in the username and password in empty in the `validate` method and pass them to the presenter in the `Login` method.

LoginActivity(View):

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoginView {

//To maintain the orientation changes
private final StateMaintainer mStateMaintainer =
        new StateMaintainer(getSupportFragmentManager(),    LoginActivity.class.getName());
@Inject
public LoginPresenter mPresenter;

@BindView(R.id.res_parent)
RelativeLayout relParent;
@BindView(R.id.txt_inp_username)
TextInputLayout inpUserName;
@BindView(R.id.edt_username)
TextInputEditText edtUsername;
@BindView(R.id.txt_inp_password)
TextInputLayout inpPassword;
@BindView(R.id.edt_password)
TextInputEditText edtPassword;

@OnClick(R.id.btn_login)
public void Login() {
    if (validate()) {
        mPresenter.loginUser(edtUsername.getText().toString(), edtPassword.getText().toString());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    //getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    setupMVP();

}

void setupMVP() {
    if (mStateMaintainer.firstTimeIn()) {
        initialize();
    } else {
        reinitialize();
    }
    /*if (mStateMaintainer.firstTimeIn()) {
        LoginPresenterImpl presenter = new LoginPresenterImpl(this);
        LoginInteractorImpl loginInteractor = new LoginInteractorImpl(presenter);
        presenter.setInteractor(loginInteractor);
        mStateMaintainer.put(presenter);
        mStateMaintainer.put(loginInteractor);
        mPresenter = presenter;
    } else {
        mPresenter = mStateMaintainer.get(LoginPresenterImpl.class.getName());
        // Updated the View in Presenter
        mPresenter.setView(this);
    }*/

}

void initialize() {
    setupComponent();
    mStateMaintainer.put(LoginPresenterImpl.class.getName(), mPresenter);
}

void reinitialize() {
    mPresenter = mStateMaintainer.get(LoginPresenterImpl.class.getName());
    mPresenter.setView(this);
    if (mPresenter == null) {
        setupComponent();
    }
}

private void setupComponent() {
    GenericApp.get(this)
            .component()
            .getLoginComponent(new LoginActivityModule(this))
            .inject(this);
}
//Validate TextInputEditText
private boolean validate() {
    Boolean isValid = true;
    List<IValidation> validation = new ArrayList<>();
    validation.add(new EditTextRequired(this, edtPassword,
            inpPassword, "Password is required"));
    validation.add(new EditTextRequired(this, edtUsername,
            inpUserName, "Username/Email is required"));

    for (IValidation v : validation) {
        if (!v.invoke()) {
            isValid = false;
        }
    }
    return isValid;
}


@Override
public void LoginSuccess(String SuccessMessage) {
    Snackbar.make(relParent, SuccessMessage, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void LoginFailure(String FailureMessage) {
    Snackbar.make(relParent, FailureMessage, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public Context getAppContext() {
    return getApplicationContext();
}

@Override
public Context getActivityContext() {
    return this;
}

@Override
public void showProgress() {
    Utils.showProgressDialog(this, "");
}

@Override
public void hideProgress() {
    Utils.hideProgessDialog(this);
}

@Override
public void showToast() {

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mPresenter.onDestroy(isChangingConfigurations());
}}
```

This is the implementation of my `LoginPresenter` interface. Here the presenter  logs in the user using the `loginUser` method.If possible I want to do the Edittext validation(for empty strings) in this method.

LoginPresenter(Presenter):

```
public class LoginPresenterImpl implements LoginPresenter {


//private final LoginInteractorImpl mInteractor;
private LoginInteractor mInteractor;
private WeakReference<LoginView> mView;

public LoginPresenterImpl(LoginView view) {
    mView = new WeakReference<>(view);
    //mInteractor = new LoginInteractorImpl(this);
}


private LoginView getView() throws NullPointerException {
    if (mView != null) {
        return mView.get();
    } else {
        throw new NullPointerException("View is not available");
    }
}

public void setInteractor(LoginInteractor interactor){
    mInteractor=interactor;
}

@Override
public void setView(LoginView view) {
    mView = new WeakReference<>(view);
}

@Override
public void loginUser(String username, String password) {
    getView().showProgress();
    mInteractor.attemptLogin(username, password);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(boolean isChangingConfiguration) {
    mView = null;
}

@Override
public Context getAppContext() {
    try {
        return getView().getAppContext();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        return null;
    }

}

@Override
public Context getActivityContext() {
    try {
        return getView().getActivityContext();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onSuccess(String SuccessMessage) {
    getView().hideProgress();
    getView().LoginSuccess(SuccessMessage);
}

@Override
public void onFailure(String FailureMessage) {
    getView().hideProgress();
    getView().LoginFailure(FailureMessage);
}}
```

This is the implementation of `LoginInteractor` interface. I've used retrofit2 library to make the http call. In the `onResponse` method it calls the `LoginPresenter`'s`onSuccess("")` or `onFailure("")` depending on server response.

LoginInteractor(Model):

```
public class LoginInteractorImpl implements LoginInteractor, Callback<LoginResponse> {

private final LoginPresenter mPresenter;

public LoginInteractorImpl(LoginPresenter mPresenter) {
    this.mPresenter = mPresenter;
}

@Override
public void attemptLogin(String username, String password) {
    Map<String, String> loginMap = new HashMap<>();
    loginMap.put("username", username);
    loginMap.put("password", password);
    LoginApi apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(LoginApi.class);
    Call<LoginResponse> call = apiInterface.LoginUser(loginMap);
    call.enqueue(this);
}

@Override
public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
    Log.v("Login", "" + response.code());
    if (response.code() == 200) {
        mPresenter.onSuccess("Login Success");
    } else {
        mPresenter.onFailure("Username or password is Incorrect");
    }


}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
    Log.v("Login", "" + t.toString());
    mPresenter.onFailure("Failed to login");
}}
```

This class is used to validate the `TextInputEditText` and to show the error message in `TextInputLayout.setError("")`.

EditTextRequired:

```
//Validate edittext and set error
public class EditTextRequired implements IValidation {

Activity context;
TextInputEditText text;
TextInputLayout Error;
String ErrorMessage;

public EditTextRequired(Activity context, TextInputEditText text, TextInputLayout Error, String ErrorMessage) {
    this.context = context;
    this.text = text;
    this.Error = Error;
    this.ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage;
}

@Override
public Boolean invoke() {

    if (text.getText().toString().trim().length() < 1) {
        Error.setError(ErrorMessage);
        requestFocus(text);
        return false;
    }
    Error.setErrorEnabled(false);
    return true;
}

private void requestFocus(View view) {
    if (view.requestFocus()) {
        context.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    }
}}
```

Also any feedback on my code will be appreciated i.e is my implementation of the android MVP pattern is correct or not.

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does in a more specific manner. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.